# How can I identify when a Kotlin type will be mapped to a Java type?

Tags: java, jvm, kotlin

## Context

Kotlin's `kotlin.String` type is [currently defined as follows (1.1.2)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.1.2/core/builtins/native/kotlin/String.kt#L23-L38):

```
public class String : Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    companion object {}

    // Operator and override function definitions.
}
```

Some extensions defined on `kotlin.String` cast the receiving instance to the `java.lang.String` type to forward method invocations. [For example (1.1.2)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.1.2/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/StringsJVM.kt#L92-L96):

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun String.toLowerCase(): String = (this as java.lang.String).toLowerCase()
```

However, nothing in the `kotlin.String` type *definition* makes it clear to me that this cast is guaranteed to succeed.

## Questions

- Is there any way to easily determine if any given Kotlin type is mapped to a corresponding Java type in this manner?
- Where does this conversion actually happen? (Looking for a link to the relevant source code if possible.)

Comment: `Where does this conversion actually happen?` What do you mean by that? Kotlin's `String` is basically a typealias of Java's `java.lang.String`

Comment: @Mibac how do you know that? It's not obvious from the source code, as I showed above, so that "aliasing" must occur somewhere. I'm looking for the _where_ part :)

Comment: I think there's a bit of compiler magic involved to make strings work like Java strings. I couldn't find documentation for it right now though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kotlin/JVM `kotlin.String` is one of the [mapped types](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) - a type that is represented with some existing JDK class in runtime.

Therefore a cast between `kotlin.String` and `java.lang.String` succeeds in runtime, even though these are two unrelated types from the point of Kotlin type system.

Comment: Ah, nice find! Armed with this information I found [this relevant class](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.1.2/core/descriptor.loader.java/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/platform/JavaToKotlinClassMap.java) from within the Kotlin repo, which defines the mappings described in the documentation. In fact the whole [`platform` directory](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/v1.1.2/core/descriptor.loader.java/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/platform) is interesting.

Comment: Also [the `Converter` type](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.1.2/j2k/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/j2k/Converter.kt).