# How does this kotlin code work?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin defines its own `String` class:

```
public class String : Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    companion object {}        
    public operator fun plus(other: Any?): String    
    public override val length: Int    
    public override fun get(index: Int): Char    
    public override fun subSequence(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int): CharSequence    
    public override fun compareTo(other: String): Int
}
```

The instances of this class are constructed via inline functions defined in `StringsJVM.kt`:

```
public inline fun String(bytes: ByteArray, offset: Int, length: Int): String =
    java.lang.String(bytes, offset, length, Charsets.UTF_8) as String
```

Questions:

1. How does the cast of `java.lang.String` to `kotlin.String` work? It is not a subtype but a separate implementation of `CharSequence`
2. Member `length` is a val with no value assigned. How does this compile? It would need to be a lateinit var

I presume there must some sort of code pre-processing going on before the compilation.

Please feel free to edit this question with a more apt title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `kotlin.String` is a [mapped type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types), which means that, when compiled into the JVM bytecode, all Kotlin usages of the `kotlin.String` type are translated to equivalent usages of `java.lang.String`.

This technique ensures compatibility of the Kotlin and Java types and at the same time allows adding Kotlin-idiomatic API to the Java types.

You can [inspect the `*.class` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538049/kotlin-bytecode-how-to-analyze-in-intellij-idea) produced by the compiler and see that they mention the `java.lang.String`.

See also: [a sililar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787176/how-can-i-identify-when-a-kotlin-type-will-be-mapped-to-a-java-type).

---

As to the compilation of the `length` property of the `kotlin.String` definition, you can see that it is actually never compiled but only serialized into the Kotlin builtins metadata, according to [the Gradle build script](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.50/core/builtins/build.gradle.kts) of the corresponding module.